# base64_encode not working and not throwing errors

Tags: php, base64

```
base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key)))) ;
```

I am using the above line to encrypt a string. But some how it is not working. The same code works fine on my pc (i am using wamp server). The problem shows up only when i put it on my linux server which is running php 5.3.27. It does not throw up any errors. The rest of the script after this line is not executed. I commented out this line and the whole script executed perfectly.

Comment: Is the `mcrypt` library installed on your server?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe remove the space between `)` and `;`

```
base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
```

Works fine for me like this:

```
$key = "testkey";
$test = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));

echo $test;
```

Comment: nope.. the code works perfectly on my laptop, but the problem comes up when i host it...